# How can I write a query which returns the maximum value in SPARQL?

Tags: database, sparql, semantic-web

I want to have a query in SPARQL to find states and the university in each state with most undergraduate students.

I tried this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?University ?State (MAX(?nu) AS ?size)
    WHERE{
        ?University dbpo:numberOfUndergraduateStudents ?nu.
        ?University a dbpo:University.
        ?University dbpo:state ?State.
        {
        SELECT ?State
            WHERE{
                ?State a dbpo:PopulatedPlace.
                ?State a dbpo:AdministrativeRegion.
                ?State dbpo:country dbpedia:United_States.
                ?State dbpo:capital ?Capital.
                FILTER(bound(?Capital))
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it does not return my expected output. it returns more than one school from one state.
Can anybody guide me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the inner SELECT (it can be placed in the outer block).

```
FILTER(bound(?Capital))
```

-- ?Capital must be bound.

Then you need

```
GROUP BY ?State
```

Put this in an inner SELECT and use the outer one to find the actually univerity(-ies) with that size,state.

Your query is technically illegal currently:

```
SELECT ?University ?State (MAX(?nu) AS ?size)
```

with no GROUP BY is wrong.  You can only select GROUP BY variables and aggregates

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you mention but still I'm getting universities in states more than once. which means it does not return the university with maximum size in each state.
Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: [SPARQL 1.1 spec, §11.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#groupby) contains: "If aggregates are used in the query level in SELECT, HAVING or ORDER BY but the GROUP BY term is not used, then this is taken to be a single implicit group, to which all solutions belong." So although the given query doesn't answer the original question, it appears to be legal. (Why DBpedia then returns more than one answer, I don't understand.)

Answer (score 2):

As AndyS says: the order in which to do things here is

1. Find the maximum for the number of undergraduate students per state,
2. Find the university or universities that have that number of undergraduate students.

The first step goes in the subquery, the second in the outer query.
Then you get this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?University ?State ?size
WHERE{
    ?University dbpo:numberOfUndergraduateStudents ?size.
    ?University a dbpo:University.
    ?University dbpo:state ?State.
    {
    SELECT ?State (MAX(?nu) as ?size)
        WHERE{
            ?State a dbpo:PopulatedPlace.
            ?State a dbpo:AdministrativeRegion.
            ?State dbpo:country dbpedia:United_States.
            ?State dbpo:capital ?Capital.
            ?University dbpo:numberOfUndergraduateStudents ?nu.
            ?University a dbpo:University.
            ?University dbpo:state ?State.
            FILTER(bound(?Capital))
        }
        GROUP BY ?State
    }
}
```